How do I use the path_provider to calculate the size of the data stored in shared_preferences
I'm working on a feature that calculates the storage space occupied by the app on the device, and I want to calculate the size to make the shared_preferences library store data. I used the path_provider to read it and found that I couldn't . Here is some of the code I use for path_provide
  void requestTempDirectory() async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    var a = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    double cache = await _getTotalSizeOfFilesInDir(tempDir);
    cacheSize = _renderSize(cache);
    print('Temp :$cache');
    update(['my_cache']);
  }

  void requestDocumentsDirectory() async {
    final tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(tempDir);
    double cache = await _getTotalSizeOfFilesInDir(tempDir);
    var cacheSized = _renderSize(cache);
    print('Documents :$cache');
    update(['my_cache']);
  }

  void requestSupportDirectory() async {
    final tempDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    double cache = await _getTotalSizeOfFilesInDir(tempDir);
    var cacheSized = _renderSize(cache);
    print('Support :$cache');
    update(['my_cache']);
  }


  void requestCacheDirectory() async {
    final tempDir = await getApplicationCacheDirectory();
    print('$tempDir');
    cachePath = tempDir.path;
    double cache = await _getTotalSizeOfFilesInDir(tempDir);
    cacheSize = _renderSize(cache);
    print('Cache :$cache');
    update(['my_cache']);
  }

// Storge
  void requestStorgeDirectory() async {
    final tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (tempDir == null) return;
    storgePath = tempDir.path;
    print('$tempDir');
    int cache = await _getTotalSizeOfFilesInDir(tempDir);
    storgeSized = _renderSize(cache);
    print('Storge :$storgeSized');
    update(['my_cache']);
  }

